# SQL Server EXEC a raw SQL query inside of the SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, which contains an external table name where I can find a value that I need (that table doesn't have any PKs/FKs, I can not change this).
The thing is, is it possible to execure a dynamic SQL query inside of the SELECT statement ?

Something like

```
SELECT Col1, 
       Col2,
       'SELECT TOP 1 Col from ' + Col3,
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Nope.  It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is *exactly* what you are looking to do, but this might be a solution if the value you would like to concatenate is going to be the same (which it looks like from the `TOP 1` in the example):

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('atest') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE atest

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[atest](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [value] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [X] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO atest (id, value, X) 
VALUES  (1, 'ONE', 'EXTRA STUFF'),
        (2, 'TWO', 'OTHER'),
        (3, 'THREE', 'NOT THIS')

DECLARE @X VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT TOP 1 X FROM atest)

SELECT [id], [value] + '-->' + @X FROM atest
```

This would result in:

```
1   ONE-->EXTRA STUFF
2   TWO-->EXTRA STUFF
3   THREE-->EXTRA STUFF
```

You could also make a temp table, or do self joins.  I think there are some solutions here to get you what you want.  Good luck!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you could consider selecting the values form Table1 into temp table and then using dynamic UPDATE statement to add the value form table specified by col3. Not elegant and have not tried on DB, but something like this might get you around problem

```
SELECT Col1, 
    Col2,
    Col3
    TopOfCol3Table = ''
INTO #TempTable1
FROM Table1

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(1024) =  '
UPDATE #TempTable1
SET TopOfCol3Table = (SELECT TOP 1 Col FROM ' + Col3 ')'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```

Answer (score -1):

You can execute TSQL commands by calling the stored procedure **sp_executesql** that takes your TSQL command text as parameter.

Here's some documentation about it: [sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

What you do with the result is all part of your implementation.